# Getting started with Gephi imports

Tags: java, eclipse, gephi

Im am trying to create a gephi project in eclipse. Right now all i want to do is set up the file architecture so i can copy and paste in the example and run it. My problem is when i do that the imports no longer work.i have downloaded the toolkit and I have added the .jar file to the build path. I think the problem is that the package i have is always the default one, but i do not know how to load the gephi package when i start a new project. My question is how do i get the imports to work and how do i start a project with the gephi package or how can i open the gephi demo through eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

To get the file architecture right i just created a new project, and gave that project the exact same name as the file downloaded on my desktop, eclipse took care of the rest.